# Raphael animate arc with <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, diagram

I'm following this tutorial (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/04/22/animated-skills-diagram/) and I want to add a legend list with the possibility to emulate the same animation into the diagram but when you put the mouse on the list. For example, if you move the mouse in the "HTML" element in the legend list, the "HTML" arc in the diagram pop as the same way as you move the mouse in the arc directly

I don't know if you understand what I'm trying to explain, I do my best sorry

But thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It makes sense, if you can put a jsfiddle or your work so far, I'm sure we can help.

Comment: Ian --> I try into a JSFIDLE but didn't work so here is my website link : http://nathancheval.fr/dev 
Thanks a lot for your help.
For the moment when you hover the HTML legend all the arc are showing up..

Comment: Hard to tell without being able to test properly. Instinctively looking at your code, what looks odd is your use of z variable and scope though, its very unclear how this is supposed to work.

Comment: I finaly make a JSFIDLE works. Here is the link if you want to see : http://jsfiddle.net/Q8KVC/1025/
And for the legend item, I just try some things so it's normal if it's messy..

Answer (score 0):

You have two main problems...

The first is that the $(".html").mouseover is inside the 'each' function, so you are setting up 5 or so mouseovers that will get executed with one hover. I assume you don't actually want this.

Then the z variable will be out of scope. You need to figure how you want to set one html element to reference a corresponding svg element. You could do that by giving them a certain id, or a hash table or array or something.

Comment: I see that every arc have and id. But I really don't know how to access to one arc with his id...